# Error while executing HQL with group by clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using the following HQL query:

```
 List<Object> object = session.createQuery("select userId, count(*) from Tweet " +
                "group by userId", Object.class).getResultList();
```

It's causing the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.query.QueryTypeMismatchException: Query
> result-type error - multiple selections: use Tuple or array   at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.checkQueryReturnType(QuerySqmImpl.java:367)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.visitQueryReturnType(QuerySqmImpl.java:328)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.(QuerySqmImpl.java:227)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractShare

what could be the reason for this?
Is it because I am selecting specific columns in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select clause is returning two things, therefore the type signature of the method should be `List<Object[]>`.  Use this version:

```java
List<Object[]> object = session.createQuery("select userId, count(*) from Tweet " +
            "group by userId", Object[].class).getResultList();
```

But note that you could also define an entity which matches the select clause.  Then, you could avoid the cumbersome `Object[]` result set type.

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly is the purpose of criteria API then?

Comment: The Criteria API is totally different than HQL/JPQL, which is what you are using in your question.

Comment: Also is there a way to write the above query in HQL, The above is more like a MySQL query could we minimize it and write it in a more structured Hibernate, HQL, Java classes way?

Comment: Actually your current query may be valid HQL already, minus possible the table alias.